# How To Insert Value From input in iframe to Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using javascript dom, and I've made my edits to a page, I don't have access to edit, only by js file.

And I created a subsite, and made a iframe by Dom, the site is an entry for a specific text

I want to link the communication between iframe and the page, which is entered in input iFrame is inserted into the page by Dom

This is the that I created:

main page **example.com**

iframe **page.example.com**

I want the element is written in iFrame and inserted into the page.

This is a input code on the page and an ID field_93873.

```
<input type="text" id="field_93873" placeholder="HERE URL VIDEO AFTER UPLOAD" value="">
```

This is what is used in iFrame (i have access):

```
<input id="upURL" value="https://example.com/LinkVideo.mp4">
```

This is the code I created DOM to be implanted into the page:

```
var x1 = document.createElement("IFRAME");
var html_content = '<iframe id="frame1" class="frame01" src="/uploadvVideoURL/index.php"></iframe>';
document.getElementById("Upload1ONE").innerHTML = html_content;
```

I just want someone who understands, and makes the code to print the input iframe to be displayed on the page.

Please :(

Comment: There is only one way of communication between your page and your iframe, it is to use   event messages

Comment: i want append chalid or innertext, innerhtml. anymore :( i need the way

Comment: You can do that directly. an iframe is like an separate window even if it is inside a page.

Comment: this is not about alert. this is about event messaging. read the documentation first, it's not very complicated  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MisterJojo  I did not understand the mechanism, is it possible to make a ready-made example based on the codes in the post?

Comment: I have the impression that you don't seem to have understood the context of your question: your html page and its iframe each have a different and independent DOM. Each of these 2 DOM ignores everything from each other and each is in a protected sandbox. They can only communicate by message.